# Flatten a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
[[(video1,4)], [(video2,5),(video3,8)], [(video1,5)], [(video5, 7), (video6,9)]...]
```

each item in this list may contain a single data pair, or a tuple, I want to change this list into

```
[(video1,4),(video2,5),(video3,8),(video1,5),(video5,7),(video6,9)...]
```

then do this:

```
for item in list:
    reqs = reqs + item[1]
    b.append(item[0])
c = set(b)
```

I don't know how to change the list structure, or how to do the same calculation based on the original list?

Comment: Do you need the `...` in the example list? it would be a working example without it.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve in the end? A set `c` of `videoX` variables and the sum of the other numbers you've listed?

Comment: @jamylak no, .... means there're lots more similar data which I don't to list them all

Comment: @Shep yes, this list contains lots of data, not just the ones I listed here, but basically that's what I want to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to flatten the list, just use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Answer (score 15):

There is a very simple way of doing this with list comprehensions.  This example has been documented in the python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
>>> # flatten a list using a listcomp with two 'for'
>>> vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> [num for elem in vec for num in elem]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Here is the solution that you would want to implement.  As per your example, this is the simplest solution

```
In [59]: your_list = [[('video1',4)], [('video2',5),('video3',8)], [('video1',5)], [('video5', 7), ('video6',9)]]

In [60]: improved_list = [num for elem in your_list for num in elem]

In [61]: improved_list
Out[61]: 
[('video1', 4),
 ('video2', 5),
 ('video3', 8),
 ('video1', 5),
 ('video5', 7),
 ('video6', 9)]
```

Comment: Interesting, but difficult to get right from memory.

Answer (score 13):

If this list is **singly-nested** (list of lists) you can do this, which I use **a lot**:

```
flat_list = sum(list_of_lists, [])
```

This works due to the fact that sum simply adds up the lists, and adding up lists works in python as expected :)

**Note**: This is inefficient and some say unreadable.

Comment: Not pythonic. Upvote just for the idea.

Answer (score 11):

To flatten one level, you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`:

```
flattened_list = itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list)
```

Comment: @Marcin: You are right, that's how it was called in NumPy. :)

Comment: Proof, as if proof were needed, that numbers are bad for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one (no libraries):

```
def plus(a,b): return a + b
reduce(plus, your_list)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a named function instead of a lambda?

Comment: just for the sake of clarity, no special reason.

Comment: This is the slowest solution (functools reduce in python 3).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain 

c = set()
reqs = 0
for vid, number in chain(*your_list): 
    c.add(vid)
    reqs += number
```

Also see related post [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python).

There should be negligible performance increase from using `chain.from_iterable(list)` rather than `chain(*list)`, but it's true that the former looks cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

to extract all tuples from a data structure ...

```
def get_tups(y):
    z = []
    if y:
        for x in y:
            if isinstance(x, tuple):
                z.append(x)
            else:
                z.extend(get_tups(x))
    return z
```

maybe ...

Comment: what happens if I call `get_tups([('foo',)])`?

Comment: since the input contains 1 tuple, you will get a list containing the 1 tuple. in other words, the output will be the same as the input ;)

Comment: And then what happens if I call it a second time? Here's a hint: http://ideone.com/zgMzq

Comment: ahh. why is z not an empty list the second time it is called?

Comment: Because you append a value to it in your code, and the expression `z=[]` is evaluated as part of the `def` statement.

Comment: get_tups([('foo',)])
get_tups([('foo',)])
.. on line 2 i pass no variable for z. therefore i would expect it to assume []

Comment: It's your job to tell the computer what to do, not hope it makes assumptions.

Comment: let me rephrase. i would expect it to default to [], since the parameter is a default parameter, and is not passed into the method. it seems to 'remember' the previous value of z. like its a global or something. i thought the scope of z was within the method itself. therefore, the second time it was called, it would re-initialize to []. sorry if i'm being dumb

Comment: I've already explained why it happens: `z=[]` is evaluated as part of the `def` statement. Incidentally, your function also doesn't cope with circular input: http://ideone.com/YOaPS

Comment: for completeness, i have fixed the code - http://ideone.com/o8PO6. thanks for your help @Marcin

Comment: Awesome. You can edit your answer - it is definitely encouraged.